# Bluetooth issues

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and I cannot activate the Bluetooth settings. It will not work even if I click on the buttons

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly do an update of the OS

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the drivers

```
sudo apt-get install bluez python-gobject python-dbus
```

Check if the hardware is present

```
sudo lshw -short | grep bluetooth
```

If it shows, then you are all set to use it.

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) for more info.